# Autoplay audio not playing

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make browser play my wolf.mp3 file 10 times. After loading the page nothing happens.

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name, audioSrc) {
    this._name = name;
    this._audioSrc = audioSrc;
  }
  makeSound() {
    let audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
    audioEl.src = this._audioSrc;
    audioEl.autoplay = true;
    document.body.appendChild(audioEl);
  }
}
let testyWolf = new Animal("wolf","audio/wolf.mp3" );
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  testyWolf.makeSound();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the [autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

The user needs to interact with the document first, i.e click somewhere on the page.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, audioSrc) {
    this._name = name;
    this._audioSrc = audioSrc;
  }
  makeSound() {
    let audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
    audioEl.src = this._audioSrc;
    audioEl.autoplay = true;
    document.body.appendChild(audioEl);
  }
}

let testyWolf = new Animal("wolf","https://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-V50-Rock-Beat-120bpm.wav" );

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  testyWolf.makeSound()
})
```

```html
<p> Click anywhere </p>
```

Put a button called i.e "Start Game" (if it's a game) somewhere so the user clicks on your page first before you attempt to autoplay sound.

Answer (score 0):

Only One audio file can be played, you could make the one file sound like many though.

anyway becouse of the `autoplay policy.` you can not auto play without the user interact with it. So i made some changes to your code and now the audio will play when you `mouseover` the body, it will look like autoplay though. look below to understand

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, audioSrc) {
    this._name = name;
    this._audioSrc = audioSrc;
    this.audioEl= "";
  }
  
  
  
   play(){
    this.audioEl.play();
   }
  
  makeSound() {
    this.audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
    this.audioEl.src = this._audioSrc;
    this.audioEl.autoplay = false;
    document.body.appendChild(this.audioEl);
    
    return this;
  }
}

var items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  items.push(new Animal("wolf","https://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-V50-Rock-Beat-120bpm.wav" ).makeSound());
}

document.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  items.forEach((item)=>
  {
    setTimeout(function(){ item.play()},200);
  });
})
```